# Tag merge / synonym request: [modelling] → [modeling]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [modelling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modelling) (20 questions) into [modeling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling) (138), and make them synonyms.

Neither of tags has wiki, but questions in both appear to be about the same topic and per my reading of [Grammar Blog article](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/modeling-or-modelling/) both spellings mean the same thing.

On a related note, merging these two tags with [model](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model) (97 questions) also looks worth considering.

---

Preference for master tag is because it has more questions.

<sub>This suggestion was made [in Whiteboard chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50284469#50284469) (twice) but somehow, not actioned. Hence, posting to meta.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I merged modelling into modeling, since that makes sense. I'm hesitant to do anything with model since it can refer to a model in the sense of a model of a system that you make when modeling, a model of a real world thing represented in software, or part of the MVC or MVVM or similar patterns.